# Disable editing of a NSTextFieldCell on right clicking on a row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I've got a view based `NSTableView` with a `NSTextFieldCell` inside. If I select a row and then right click on the same row, the table view puts the field into edit mode after a short delay! Right Clicking should only show the context menu (which it does) but ignore editing the field.

How can I stop this behavior? I'm not doing anything non-standard. I can see in the debugger that the table seems to call `_delayMakeFirstResponder` when I right click on a row, which then seems to put the field into edit mode since it was already selected.

Comment: Is the `NSTextFieldCell` inside a `NSTextField` inside a `NSTableCellView`? How is the context menu implemented? Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Willeke Yes that's how it is exactly, I'm lazy recreating the setup but as I said, there's nothing non standard about this setup, standard stuff.

Comment: Is the context menu the default text editing context menu?

Comment: Did you find a solution here?

Comment: @Craigt checkout my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct solution to this. Override `NSTableView` and the `NSResponder` method `validateProposedFirstResponder:forEvent:`. There, return NO.

This is what I did. `m_menuWasShowing` is set to `true` inside `- (NSMenu *) menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent`

```objectivec
- (BOOL)validateProposedFirstResponder:(NSResponder *)responder forEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
  if (event.type == NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown || event.type == NSEventTypeLeftMouseUp) {
    // Ignore first left click if menu was previously showing
    if (m_menuWasShowing) {
      m_menuWasShowing = NO;
      return NO;
    }
  }
  return [super validateProposedFirstResponder:responder forEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the textcell behaviour fron Editable to None, in the design, Or you can programatically try this,

```
[TableColumn setEditable:NO]; //to disble column editing
[[TableView cell]setEditable:NO]; //to disable textcell editing
```

Comment: I don't want to make it non-editable. The idea us to left-click and get into edit mode, and right click and only see the context menu. Right now it's putting it into Edit mode on a right-click too.