# How to prevent right-click textfield renaming in NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nstextfield, nsoutlineview

I am having a NSOutlineView in which the textfield is editable by either pressing return or using the right click. I am also overriding the `menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu?` to menu based on which row is clicked

When I right click on the textfield, it opens the correct menu as expected but it also makes the textfield to go into edit mode. Is there a way to handle this behaviour?

[image: Wrong]

However, when I click outside the textfield then it works without setting the textfield in edit mode:

[image: Right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar NSTableView where right-clicking is supported to display a menu, but the fields are also directly editable. I took a look to see why/how the editing doesn't seem to be a problem in my case, and I narrowed the behavior down to the presence of this line of code in my NSTableView subclass:

```
// This trick convinces the accessibility system to bother checking whether
// we have a menu to export to e.g. VoiceOver.
[self setMenu:[[NSMenu alloc] init]];
```

As you can see from the comment, the rationale for this "setting an empty menu" was for a different reason than avoiding the editing behavior you're seeing, but it appears to have the side-effect of also fixing that.

So, please try adding a line like the above to your NSOutlineView subclass and see if it fixes the problem!

Comment: Ah! by setting the menu on the outline view and using the delegate method `menuNeedsUpdate` works. Thanks so much .

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem trying to get my Swift-based app on Monterey working. I was surprised there was not a more simple/obvious solution, but here is what I came up with:

```
class MyOutlineView: NSOutlineView {

    // prevent text field from becoming editable when context menu is used
    override func validateProposedFirstResponder(_ responder: NSResponder,
                                                 for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool
    {
        guard let validEvent = event,
              contextMenuTriggered(event: validEvent),
              selectedRow != -1,
              selectedRow == row(at: convert(validEvent.locationInWindow, from: nil))
        else {
            return super.validateProposedFirstResponder(responder, for: event)
        }
        return false
    }

    private func contextMenuTriggered(event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return event.modifierFlags.contains(.control)
            && (event.type == .leftMouseDown || event.type == .leftMouseUp)
    }
}
```

This detects if a control-click happened on the selected row in the outline view, then blocks it from receiving focus so the text field does not become editable.

Credit for this approach goes to the answer provided by @strangetimes here: [Disable editing of a NSTextFieldCell on right clicking on a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432751/disable-editing-of-a-nstextfieldcell-on-right-clicking-on-a-row)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I added `(event.type == .rightMouseDown || event.type == .rightMouseUp)` to `contextMenuTriggered(event:)` to also account for right clicks, but unfortunately when the text field is first responder the context menu doesn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified [@ediblebits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794576/656488)'s answer to also account for right clicks (not only control clicks) that wouldn't disable the edited text field's context menu:

```
class MyOutlineView: NSOutlineView {
    
    override func validateProposedFirstResponder(_ responder: NSResponder, for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
        if let event = event, window?.firstResponder == self && (event.type == .rightMouseDown || event.type == .rightMouseUp || (event.modifierFlags.contains(.control) && (event.type == .leftMouseDown || event.type == .leftMouseUp))) {
            return false
        }
        return super.validateProposedFirstResponder(responder, for: event)
    }
    
}
```